# EF Core Oracle Timestamp with Timezone to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

With **EF Core 2.2.6** I am saving `DateTime` --> `Oracle Timestamp(7)` with Time zone : `30.07.19 18:13:23,283000000 +02:00`. But when I am reading it back its : `30.07.19 20:13:23,283000000 +02:00`.

How can I exlpicitly mention in EF core no `DateTime` convertions?

Comment: Use `DateTimeOffset`, not `DateTime`. DateTime can only hold UTC or "local" values, whatever Local means.

Comment: I tried with DateTimeOffset, same issue. How can I Speicify timeoffset / time zone in EF Core? Or Do i need to explicitly convert Datetme --> Localtime on every tiime after read / to UTC before write to DB??

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with DateTimes and Timezones is between [complicated and able to drive you mad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). However I have 3 rules that make working with them manageable:

1. Always store and retrieve the UTC value
2. Avoid storing or transmission as string
3. If you can not follow rule 2 (like with XML), at least pick a fixed enconding and culture to use on every endpoint. You really do not want to add those to your worries.

However there are some scenarios (like a Calendar) where you have to deal with timezones instead.

Also note that `0.07.19 18:13:23,283000000 +02:00` is not actually the value. This is a String Representation of the value, using the users settings for details like formating and timezone.

Comment: @Izzy: If he has issues with the timezone, he is definitely not storing in UTC. And considering the difference is exactly equal to the UTC+2 value, he has those issues.

Comment: I can not change every time  datetime-2, Is there any way in EF Core to specify explicitly mention do not covert any datetime value.

Comment: How to store and retrieve the value as UTC in EF Core / DateTimeOffset? I tried with DateTIme and DateTimeOffset both. But how  can I speicfy UTC in EF Core ? in context or modelBuilder or directly on Entity?  and How?

Comment: @Srikanth This is the kind of thing you have to have solved when filling the Database with data. Trying to fix it in restrospect is "dealing with Timezones", the very thing you really want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Changed the driver from Devart to Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 2.19.30

1) Devart driver got some issues with Timezone offset.
 reading with timstamp + offset and writing to DB with out offset.

2) Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 2.19.30 released a week back is the perfect solution for me. It solved 1) Timezone issue and 2) performance issue (10X faster). 3) some other small issues in my web application.

Thank you.